# How to set emacs to handle all unknown file types as bash

Tags: bash, emacs

How do I configure emacs to get the same behaviour as when I tell vim to `let g:is_bash=1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your .emacs file:

```
(setq sh-shell-file "/bin/bash")
```